# Why ping to a specific address is different from country to another?

Tags: networking, ping, traceroute

I was working on a server outside my country, and the ping was around 90, I moved to other country and still working on the same server, both countries have the same distance, ISP, internet speed, WIMAX technology. and both of them was close to the WIMAX bridge.

I made some `tracert` commands and found both countries connect to the same ٍSCC, the same point.

Why in my country the ping was 90, and in other country was around 200?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing apples and oranges.  Your endpoint is the same, but your starting points are not.  You say the starting points are roughly the same distance, but in the virtual world, things dont travel in a straight line, or by the same methods.

If you are on Windows, run the command `pathping` to your destination from both points and that will most likely show you the difference between the two paths.

Example: `pathping superuser.com`

Pathping will show you the route like `tracert`, but will also ping each of the paths to show latency.  You will see the different path each route takes, as well as the latency to each hop.  That information will show you why one route takes longer than the other.

Comment: "in the virtual world, things dont travel in a straight line" extremely true, maybe they have different routers, or bad infrastructure old WiMax bridge. It's impossible to compare it, let me think in that more deeply