# Why is ping time to two ip address location fairly close to each other so different?

Tags: networking, ping

I am based in India and I am using rackspace virtual server in Hong Kong. Also, I am communicating to a external website hosted in Hong Kong. So, there are three computer end-points to consider as follows:

1) A - My home pc in India
2) B - Rackspace virtual server in Honk Kong
3) C - External server in Hong Kong.

Now, the ping time from B to C is roughly 2-3 ms, which is to be expected as they are fairly close geographically to each other. But ping time from A to B is roughly 300 ms and ping time from A to C is roughly 150 ms. Since both B and C are located are roughly equal distance to A, why is there so much difference in ping time?

Traceert(partial) from A to C

```
  4    38 ms    36 ms    37 ms  125.18.13.137
  5   121 ms   123 ms   124 ms  182.79.252.6
  6   125 ms   124 ms   130 ms  vlan65.te13-2.br01.sin02.pccwbtn.net [63.218.229.81]
  7   127 ms   127 ms   126 ms  att.tenge13-4.br01.hkg04.pccwbtn.net [63.218.2.122]
  8   157 ms   155 ms   156 ms  165.87.76.214
  9   128 ms   129 ms   129 ms  32.114.131.30
```

Tracert(partial) from A to B

```
  4    39 ms    36 ms    37 ms  125.18.13.137
  5   168 ms   168 ms   168 ms  182.79.222.17
  6   184 ms   172 ms   179 ms  40ge1-3.core1.lon2.he.net [195.66.224.21]
  7   174 ms   172 ms   172 ms  100ge5-1.core1.par2.he.net [184.105.223.254]
  8   272 ms   273 ms   272 ms  10ge3-1.core1.sin1.he.net [184.105.222.114]
  9   277 ms   276 ms   273 ms  10ge6-1.core1.hkg1.he.net [184.105.223.189]
 10   253 ms   254 ms   254 ms  agc1-10G.hkix.net [123.255.90.175]
 11   266 ms   269 ms   269 ms  xe0-3-1.gw1.hkg3.asianetcom.net [61.14.157.81]
 12   255 ms   255 ms   254 ms  61.8.56.3
 13   255 ms   256 ms   255 ms  edge4.hkg30-core1a.hkg1.rackspace.net [120.136.47.136]
 14   274 ms   275 ms   276 ms  dcpe1-core1b.hkg1.rackspace.net [120.136.47.173]
 15   256 ms   257 ms   255 ms  119.9.64.67
```

(I have removed the first 3 and last line from the tracert output to remove personal infromation)

Comment: There is no way to answer this without traceroute details... For example A to B might take a detour through Ireland.  This can't be answered without more detail.

Comment: @Tyson, I have posted the tracert results. Probably a rookie question, but shouldn't ping take the shortest path.

Comment: That's relative... Let's say rackspaces uses backbone providers A, C, D.  Let's say you other server only has access to the backbone provider B.   The best route may vary drastically. As you can see from your own traceroutes.  That's way oversimplified but it shows you why.

Comment: Your traceroute data shows exactly why. 2x the hops (5 vs 11) ~= 2x the delay (150 vs 300). Why would you expect it to be significantly less than that from A to B?

Comment: @krowe, both B and C are located geographically close to each other in Hong Kong as can be verified from ping times from B to C. Hence, I expected time from A to B and A to C to be fairly close to each other. May be I do not understand very well the concept of how ping works. I'll research further into it.

Comment: @amitchaudhary Geographic proximity is only part of the equation.  Routing path is the other part of the equation, so you have your answer.  They are on different networks.

Comment: It's not how ping works that your not understanding.  It's how the internet is routed that comes into play.  All the Internet backbone providers have agreements to route each other's traffic... But it goes further than that, for example they prefer to use there own fiber first, after that they may prefer one over another.   The route from A to B and A to C can be very different.  And the route back may or may not be the same or similar. You have no control over these routes.

Comment: It looks like A to B is being routed from India through London, Paris, Singapore and then to Hong Kong. That explains the delay. There's not much you can do Rio change this either as it has to do with routing tables not under your control.

Comment: BTW, a traceroute of B to C and C to B may be interesting as well (and may not be the same path)

Comment: Thank you @Tyson heavyd Paul for explaining about the routing path. That clarifies my doubt.

Comment: The only thing in my mind like what @heavyd said, It's to hard to compare pings, I made a simuler test to my server and have different result too  [check this article](http://superuser.com/questions/958573/why-ping-to-a-specific-address-is-different-from-country-to-another/958595#958595)